# How to use auto complete extender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i am having two dropdownlist one showing name of table in my database and other showing the columns name corresponding to that table .I have one textbox in which i  want to display records of that column like auto complete extender.

e.g. i have selected table name as employee in first dropdown and column name as EmployeeName in second dropdown ..now i textbox if i have enter "a" than all the EmployeeName starting with "a" should be displayed in textbox..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Comment: yes like this but i don't want to use any web service.Can't we use this without using any service???????????????

Comment: It's simply a method in your page's code-behind file, that has the WebMethod and ScriptMethod attributes.